# A word that means "Someone who risks their life to find out and tell the truth"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means "Someone who risks their life to find out and tell the truth”?

This word would mean they will risk their lives for nothing to find out the truth and tell others.

Comment: Hi Bryan, welcome to EL&U. To help us provide the answer you're looking for, please include a *sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: A reporter... especially a war correspondent.

Comment: What does "risk their lives for nothing" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Whistleblower.
Example of context: Julian Assange released the documents on WikiLeaks revealing corruption and bought a plane ticket to an undisclosed destination.

Comment: That’s a good suggestion. Your example would be better, though, if you actually used the suggested word.

Comment: I think a whistleblower only meets the latter part of the definition: risking much to tell others while not implying any risk taken to uncover the truth: the whistleblower just happens to know the truth (e.g., by chance, by virtue of their position, or by taking risks to discover the truth).

Answer (score 0):

Whistleblower is a good suggestion but he is one who already knows the truth and comes out as a witness telling it out, not necessarily making ever possible effort to 'find' it.

If the connotation has to remain positive, a [philosopher](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/philosophy) is one who dedicates much of his life to find out the meaning of life and expounds it for others. And what truth can be more worth seeking than what is life and why are we here. :)

> **Philosophy -**  "the rational investigation of questions about existence and knowledge and ethics"

`Example Usage : 
The Philosopher left no stone unturned to educate the masses about what he thought was the truth of life and how to go about it.`

I think [Inquisitor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inquisitor) is also a word that comes to mind but it is used as an aggressive and negative term to refer to someone who can go to any extent to find out the truth and is very excessive and harsh in the process.

> **Inquisitor -**  "one who inquires or makes inquisition,  
> especially : one who is unduly harsh, severe, or hostile in making an inquiry"

`Example Usage : 
The mysterious murder case at the 5th Avenue in Berlin involved a series of Inquisitors who made every effort to trace the culprit.`

Comment: Interesting. However, pondering the meaning of life isn't usually associated with risking one's own life; inquisition, more so. (But the downvote wasn't mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Three possible candidates come to my mind.

My favorite is **martyr**. Definition of Cambridge Dict says a martyr is someone

> to be killed or be made to suffer because of their beliefs.

You can describe the person as a martyr of truth.

The second one is **champion**. So the person in question is a champion of truth.

Or they can simply be a **truth-seeker**.

Hope it helps!